# PyQGIS custom color ramp raster dataset

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, color-ramp

I want to create a custom raster color ramp using PyQGIS in a standalone app.

I have found some examples about this task, for example:

```
    s=QgsRasterShader()
    c=QgsColorRampShader()
    c.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
    i=[]
    i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(30,QtGui.QColor('#d7191c'),'400'))
    i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(150,QtGui.QColor('#fdae61'),'900')) 
    c.setColorRampItemList(i)
    s.setRasterShaderFunction(c)
    ps=QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(lyr.dataProvider(),1,s)
    lyr.setRenderer(ps)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

That code works fine in Python Console but I have some questions.
How can I save that image with new color ramp to a new image (with new colors) in a standalone app?